# Having an unlimmitted number of back up files with limitted size in Java - log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I know we can give a maxFileSize to limit the size of a log file logged by the log4j RollingFileAppender. And there's a parameter called maxBackupIndex to limit the number of files that has been backed up.

My Question : If I want to have an unlimited number of back up files with limited file size how can I do it?

```
<appender name="STATICDATA" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20" />
        <param name="File" value="/path/to/log/file/Data.log" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%X{StaticDataTraceId}] [%c] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: `maxBackupIndex` is defined as `int type` and it can take `max value` as `2,147,483,647`. This number of file as a daily back up is enough. Why do you want to have infinite number of files?

Comment: Because I want to limit each log file size to 10KB and I don't know how much Bytes will there be to log.

Comment: Can you put a comment or answer with votes please? I searched and tried several ways. After asked it.

Comment: Depending on filesystem used, max number of files limit may be encountered much, much quicker than in @Rahul answer (FAT32 anyone?)

Comment: Ok. What i want to happen is not to miss any log while logging files with a limited size.

Answer (score 1):

You cant have unlimited number of files anyway because of how file system works - for example in NTFS, there is limit of 2^32 files on your disk.

Thus I would recommend to set it to maximum value of integer `<param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2147483647" />`, maybe your file system cant even support that many files :).